# how to find the query console on mongoDB in PyCharm?

Tags: mongodb, console, pycharm

how to find the query console on mongoDB in PyCharm?, in other databases like MySQL, it's right click on the database name and "Jump to Query Console..." but there is no such option in mongoDB. The mongo plugin is installed and working fine, all queries in terminal are working as well. [Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG5UH.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was with installing the correct drivers of mongoDB in PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

Select a **collection** from Database->mongodb->collection explorer and right click->Query Console
or use Ctrl+Maj+Q after selecting a collection.

use plugin Key Promoter X to be warn when you miss using shortcuts.